# Is it possible to set the number of items in a list dynamically?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view with following limitations:

1. Number of items in the list = how many items can be visible. lets say on small screen 3, on normal size devices 4, on tablet 6, etc.
2. List must not be scrollable.

Item 1 is my concern. I guess I need to calculate the height of listView and height of a row and pass X number of rows to adapter to populate it. Is that right? Is there a simpler solusion?

Answer (score 2):

WHat you want isn't a ListView then.  The entire point of a ListView is efficient view recycling and scrolling.  If you don't want that, you're better off with another solution-  possibly TableView or a customized LinearLayout.